# How to make a count down reset

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a count down so that every 20 sec an alert pops up. I want it to go from 20 to 0 to 20 over and over. I have it working, but it only works once. The rage function dosen't need to be changed, it's the msg function i'm having trouble with. Here's my code.

```js
function rage() {
  var i = document.getElementsByName("msg")[6];
  var message = document.getElementById("message");
  const affichemsg = document.querySelector("msg");

  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    message.innerHTML += "Es-tu près ";
  }
}

setInterval(rage, 350);
var decompteur = setInterval(msg, 1000);
var temps;

function msg() {
  var idTemps = document.getElementById("temps");
  temps = parseInt(idTemps.innerHTML);

  temps = temps - 1;

  idTemps.innerHTML = temps;

  if (--temps <= 0) {
    alert("!!!!!ES-TU PRÈS!!!!!");
    clearInterval(temps);
    msg();
    idTemps = 20;
    var decompteur = setInterval(msg, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
.titre2 {
  width: 650px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 35px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.bouton {
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border-width: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.boutonOui {
  background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
}

.boutonOui:hover {
  background-color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="titre2">Es-tu près</h1>
</div>
<button
  class="bouton boutonOui"
  id="boutonOui"
  onclick="window.location.href='jeu_educatifs2.html'"
>
  Oui
</button>
<div id="temps">20</div>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="msg" value="6"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first problem here is that you don't use correctly the method `clearInterval`. It takes as argument the id of the "timer" created with `setInterval`. `setInterval` return directly the id so actually stored it in your variable `decompteur` and you should use something like that to clear the timer : `clearInterval(decompteur)`.
Also be sure to reset the idTemps with `idTemps.innerHTML = 20`. Then I don't really understand... Why would you clear the interval then rebuild the same again when you can just set the `idTemps.innerHTML` so your interval will use the 20 for `temps` at the next iteration ?

PS: ça fait plaisir de voir un peu de français sur stack :)

You should rewrite your code this way :

```js
function rage() {
  var i = document.getElementsByName("msg")[6];
  var message = document.getElementById("message");
  const affichemsg = document.querySelector("msg");

  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    message.innerHTML += "Es-tu près ";
  }
}

setInterval(rage, 350);
var decompteur = setInterval(msg, 1000);

function msg() {
  var idTemps = document.getElementById("temps");

  var temps = parseInt(idTemps.innerHTML) - 1;

  idTemps.innerHTML = temps;

  if (--temps == 0) {
    alert("!!!!!ES-TU PRÈS!!!!!");
    idTemps.innerHTML = "20";
  }
}
// when you need to, stop decompteur with : 
// clearInterval(decompteur);
```

```css
.titre2 {
  width: 650px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 35px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.bouton {
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border-width: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.boutonOui {
  background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
}

.boutonOui:hover {
  background-color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="titre2">Es-tu près</h1>
</div>
<button class="bouton boutonOui" id="boutonOui" onclick="window.location.href='jeu_educatifs2.html'">
Oui
</button>
<div id="temps">20</div>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="msg" value="6"></div>
```

This keep as much of your code as possible, but as Rojo said, your code is very inefficent and there are a lot of things to improve.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your code is very inefficient. Rather than having your variable `temps` read from the DOM, you should have the variable update itself:

```
var temps = 20;
function msg() {
  --temps;
}
setInterval(msg, 1000);
```

Second, you shouldn't be including `var` inside of that `if` statement:

```
if (countdown === 0) {
  alert("!!!!!ES-TU PRÈS!!!!!");
  clearInterval(decompteur);
  // msg(); // You don't need this
  temps = 20;
  decompteur = setInterval(msg, 1000); // I removed the var
}
```

Also, you had your variables mixed up (which I fixed)

```js
function rage() {
  var i = document.getElementsByName("msg")[6];
  var message = document.getElementById("message");
  const affichemsg = document.querySelector("msg");

  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    message.innerHTML += "Es-tu près ";
  }
}

setInterval(rage, 350);
var decompteur = setInterval(msg, 1000);
var temps = 20;
var idTemps = document.getElementById("temps"); // I also moved this outside

function msg() {
  --temps;

  idTemps.innerHTML = temps;

  if (temps === 0) {
    alert("!!!!!ES-TU PRÈS!!!!!");
    clearInterval(decompteur);
    //msg(); //You don't need this
    temps = 20;
    decompteur = setInterval(msg, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
.titre2 {
  width: 650px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 35px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.bouton {
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border-width: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.boutonOui {
  background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
}

.boutonOui:hover {
  background-color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="titre2">Es-tu près</h1>
</div>
<button
  class="bouton boutonOui"
  id="boutonOui"
  onclick="window.location.href='jeu_educatifs2.html'"
>
  Oui
</button>
<div id="temps">20</div>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="msg" value="6"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code prints the counter value each second and every 20 seconds it prints ALERT. Try to use a similar code for your example because your code is not very clear.

```
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  counter++;
  if (counter % 20 == 0) {
    console.log("ALERT! ");
  }
  console.log("Counter Value: " + (counter % 20));
}, 1000);
```